# How can I change the color of an MGLPolyline?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, polyline

How can I change the color of a MGLPolyline after its already been created?

I have this code I'm trying to make work in the didSelect annotation delegate method: `chosenPolyline?.polyline //= UIColor.green`

I have [looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566855/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-mglpolyline). But the answer does not work after the lines creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that what needs to be done is you need to create a custom object for the polyline. The default `MGLPolyline` does not support this.

Add a custom polyline like so:

```
class CustomPostPolyline: MGLPolyline {
    var color: UIColor!
}
```

Put this in your `didSelect`:

```
self.mapView.removeAnnotation(chosenPolyline!.polyline!)
chosenPolyline!.polyline!.lineColor = UIColor.green
self.mapView.addAnnotation(chosenPolyline!.polyline!)
```